# how to append to an array in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm having a little issue with arrays in groovy. I am performing a data driven test where I am using a CSV and I am iterating through groovy script steps. What I am trying to do is for each iteration of my soap request, i should receive two flight ids. I want to place each set of the two flights ids in an array, so the array should just keep adding flight ids in the array:

Example:

```
After Iteration 1: [[123, 321]]
After Iteration 2: [[123.321. 454, 345]]
```

The problem I am having is that it is not adding into the array but instead replacing the values already in the array. So it looks like below:

```
After Iteration 1: [[123, 321]]
After Iteration 2: [[454, 345]]
```

How can I append the flightids in the array?

Below is the code:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def response = context.expand( '${SOAP Request#Response}'  )
def parsedxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)


def flights = parsedxml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'FlightId'}[[0],[1]]


def flightsarray = [];

flightsarray.push(flights)

context.setProperty('flights', flights)
context.setProperty('flightsarray', flightsarray)

log.error flightsarray.toString()
```

FYI I tried replacing     `flightsarray.push(flights)` with `flightsarray << flights` but it does the same thing.

Comment: `flightsarray += flights`

Comment: You have shown array of arrays, is that a mistake instead of just array? And edit the question and post the screen shot of test case structure and mention the present script's test step name.

Comment: Would you mind showing your xml as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually `.push(), << , +=` do almost the same.

I think your problem that you are expecting local script variable `flightsarray` will keep the value from the previous run. but actually it's always new and initiated with empty array.

You could append results to a file at the end of your script. Like this:

```
new File("path to file").append("${flightsarray.join(',')}\n")
```

A tricky way and could bring a lot of questions how and when to reset or store those global variables:

```
class Global{
    static def flightsarray=[]
}

Global.flightsarray.add(  new Date()  )

log.info(Global.flightsarray)
```

each time you execute this script it will add more and more dates into array.

beware when you change this script - it will be recompiled and you will loose all data in it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that among other things you set `flightsarray`
property in the `context`.

So the intuitive solution is: Start the next iteration from
reading `flightsarray` from the context.

Probably you should write:

```
def flightsarray = context.getProperty('flightsarray') ?: []
```

Breaking down into steps:

- Declare the variable,
- Try to assign it the respective property from the context.
- If nothing has been read, assign an empty table.